# JAVA return longest value if a string contains any of the items from a List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following array of code types:

```
["sample_code","code","formal_code"]
```

and the following ids:

```
String id="123456789_sample_code_xyz";
String id2="91343486_code_zxy";
```

I want to extract the code type from the ids

this is my code snippet:

```
    String codeTypes[] = {"sample_code","code","formal_code"};
    String id= "123456789_sample_code_xyz";
    String codeType = Arrays.stream(codeTypes).parallel().filter(id::contains).findAny().get();
    System.out.println(codeType);
```

it doesnt work with the 1st id, because it returns "code" instead of "sample_code", I want to get the longest code type.

```
for the 1st id the code type should be "sample_code"
for the 2nd id the code type should be "code"
```

Comment: what exactly do you want it to return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for the longest code types first. This means the following changes to your code:

1. Sort the code types by length descending.
2. Don’t use a parallel stream. A parallel stream hasn’t got an order. A sequential stream makes sure the code types are checked in order.
3. Use `findFirst()`, not `findAny()` to make sure you get the first match.

So it becomes:

```
    String codeTypes[] = { "sample_code", "code", "formal_code" };
    Arrays.sort(codeTypes, Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed());

    String id = "123456789_sample_code_xyz";
    Optional<String> codeType = Arrays.stream(codeTypes).filter(id::contains).findFirst();
    codeType.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Now output is:

> sample_code

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ids = { "123456789_sample_code_xyz", "91343486_code_zxy" };
        String[] codeTypes = { "sample_code", "code", "formal_code" };
        String max;
        for (String id : ids) {
            max = "";
            for (String codeType : codeTypes) {
                if (id.contains(codeType)) {
                    if (max.length() < codeType.length()) {
                        max = codeType;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(id + " : " + max);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123456789_sample_code_xyz : sample_code
91343486_code_zxy : code
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you run the strem in parallel, you cannot predict which of the streams finds first a matching pattern. I your case (also in mine when I tried your code snippet) the second stream which looked for "code" was faster, and the whole stream terminates because you just want "findAny()".

Remove the "parallel" and your code works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, stream API is not suitable for every problem. I think you can use a non-stream version to solve your problem.

I just looped over `codeTypes` array and for every codeType, have replaced `idx` with empty string then calculate its length and find min length between `idX` string and replace. 
now if `minSize` length with `replace` string length is the same, then it is the candidate for the final result.  `minSize != id.length()` is for when the time that there is not any codeType.

```
private static String findCodeType(String id, String[] codeTypes) {
    int minSize = id.length();
    String codeType = "NotFound";
    for (String code : codeTypes) {
        String replace = id.replaceAll(code, "");
        minSize = Integer.min(minSize, replace.length());
        if (minSize == replace.length() && minSize != id.length())
            codeType = code;
    }
    return codeType;
}
```